# Converting date formats in sql

Tags: sql-server, date

Recently I am facing a problem while working with date formats. In the table below I have following dates which is obtained while querying in microsoft SQL Server management studio 2014

```
select [Month Ending Date] from drug_practise 

dates
12/1/2016
11/1/2016
10/1/2016
9/1/2016
8/1/2016
```

But I need to convert these dates into a proper format such as YYYY-mm-dd, so I used the following code:-

```
select convert(date,[Month Ending Date],103) from drug_practise
```

but it throws error as follows :-

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Anyone can help me how to deal with the dates and avoid such errors ?

Comment: When providing sample dates, it's useful to include dates beyond the 12th of the month. This seems blindingly obvious, but needs repeating now and again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has already been answered.
Have you tried https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date ?

Comment: This is for [tag;sql-server], not [tag:mysql]. It will help if you [edit] your question to tell us the version; date stuff has made progress in that software.

Comment: Olivier Picault I have tried all these methods but My sql throws this error -''STR_TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

Comment: O. Jones I have mentioned the version of sql now

Comment: Dates don't have formats. Visual representation of dates do. Store your dates as proper date or datetime columns and let the visual layer care about formating, and the DB about data storage and querying.

Comment: You're not new. You obviously have some level of skill in tsql. You are now discovering the problems of using the wrong datatype. Your problem - which may be unfixable - is that you have values in that column that are not dates or do not have the expected format. The few values you do show can be converted without error as demonstrated [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04124aae484a115b2e058ecee4e3a8e3)

Comment: Alejandro you mean shall I change the format from varchar to date while importing ?

Comment: SMor I think it works for you there but when I try running that in mssql server it shows - 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'

Comment: The fiddle should work for anyone. Are you saying the fiddle generates an error when you running it? But it obviously will not work on your actual table because - as i stated - you have values that cannot be converted. That is why you should not store dates as strings. If you are importing this data, then change your table and your import process. If the problem is with the source data (and it seems it might be), then you need to talk with your peers, boss, client and discuss what to do with the rows that have these problems.

Comment: I figured out the problem by using 'select [Month_Ending_Date],TRY_CONVERT(date,Month_Ending_Date,103) as check_1 from Practise where TRY_CONVERT(date,Month_Ending_Date,103) is NULL' and saw there were some unusual characters present in the date column. @SMor your suggestion works after I removed those characters

Comment: @noob_python Yes, I mean, you should **never** store a string when you're handling a date. Let the server handle the dates, and convert to a proper format only at the very last step, right before displaying somewhere.

Comment: @Alejandro why I got '-1' in my question ?

Comment: The normal reason for a downvote, @noob_python , is due to what the tooltip for it says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I would guess that it is due to a lack of an [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should try format 104 instead of 103 if the first 2 digits represent the day - at least this worked well with the examples provided:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(myDateStr CHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('12/1/2016')
,('11/1/2016')
,('10/1/2016')
,('9/1/2016')
,('8/1/2016')

SELECT myDateStr, TRY_CONVERT(DATE, myDateStr, 104) AS myDate, TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TRY_CONVERT(DATE, myDateStr, 104), 23) AS myDateStrNew
  FROM @t
```

If the first two digits represent the month, you can try using format 0 instead:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(myDateStr CHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('12/1/2016')
,('11/1/2016')
,('10/1/2016')
,('9/1/2016')
,('8/1/2016')

SELECT myDateStr, TRY_CONVERT(DATE, myDateStr, 0) AS myDate, TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TRY_CONVERT(DATE, myDateStr, 0), 23) AS myDateStrNew
  FROM @t
```